string html into cell excel
I have a string like this string:
htmlString = "<img src=\"https://dev.azure.com/hungtrinh25197/ffda2280-d6d0-45d9-80ce-14da52703545/_apis/wit/attachments/d3fc19e0-5e4b-42b6 -9759-734a366c777b?fileName=image.png\" alt=Image><br><div><b>ádasdasd<br><br><br><i><b style=\"box-sizing:border- box;\">ádasdasd</b><b style=\"box-sizing:border-box;\">ádasdasd</b><b style=\"box-sizing:border-box;\">ádasdasd </b><b style=\"box-sizing:border-box;\">ádasdasd</b><b style=\"box-sizing:border-box;\">ádasdasd</b></ i><br></b></div>";

How do I put the correct html tag format into a cell in excel? In the above string, there is an img tag containing the path to the image and I also want the image to be displayed.
I used sheet.Cells["A1"].HtmlString = htmlString; of aspose but did not achieve the expected results

Excel isn't a web page. Excel won't just connect to an unknown, potentially unsafe tracking site either

I think you may insert the image into the Excel worksheet cell as linked picture from web address. Please make sure the picture’s URL is correct and accessible, so the picture will be downloaded every time the Excel file is opened in Microsoft Excel. The image will not be physically embedded into the Excel document, but it points to a web resource. Aspose.Cells supports this feature, see the document (https://docs.aspose.com/cells/net/insert-a-linked-picture-from-web-address/) for your reference.
